# Unable to find column with logical name in org.hibernate.mapping.Table and its related supertables and secondary tables

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

When I try to run my Application Class it gives me the following error:

> 2021-04-26 16:20:47.551 ERROR 14416 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Unable to find column with logical name: property_id in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(property) and its related supertables and secondary tables

From looking at that it feels to me like I might've named it incorrectly, but even when I went into the table and copied field names directly it didn't fix the issue.

The Property entity is as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "property")
public class Property {

  @Id
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "property_id", referencedColumnName = "property_id")
  private Address address;
  // other fields
```

With its table structure being:

[image: Structure of property table]

While the Address entity it's connected to is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "property_id")
  private Long propertyID;
  // other fields
```

With table structure:

[image: Structure of address table]

As you can see I have the names correct, and I believe my datasource is correctly formatted, if I use a column name that isn't in the table IntelliJ throws a warning saying it cannot resolve the column, which I don't get as they're written now.

This is my first big project using JPA so I might be missing something obvious but any help would be much appreciated, I've looked at other solutions and tried some of the suggestions but they all seem to be slightly different and not applicable to what I'm trying. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "property")
    public class Property {

        @Id
        private Long id;

        @OneToOne
        @MapsId
        @JoinColumn(name="property_id")
        private Address address;

        ...
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "address")
    public class Address {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "property_id")
        private Long propertyID;

        ...
    }
```

See the [Hibernate ORM documentation for Derived Identifiers](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-derived).

Comment: Thank you! That seems to have fixed things, just to check my understanding is correct; You use @ Id for the type and name of the column as if it were a standalone entity, and then @ MapsId is for pointing to the table it's getting the value from?

Comment: Yes, `@MapsId` tells Hibernate ORM that the value of the id in `Property` is derived from `Address`